# ListFragments java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created

Tags: android, listview, fragment

i'am having problem with ListFragments. 
i have two lists, and two ListFragments, i have them inside a viewPager.
there is a method inside the ListFragment class which is to scroll to a specific
location in that list, when a user clicks an item in list 1,the viewPager needs to
scroll to the next fragment, and then i call the scroll method to scroll to the item relevant. everything works fine, until i change rotation. then i get this

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created

now i've read all the related questions in this site that i found, and it is true that when i get inside the scroll method, i cannot do the scroll on account that the list doesn't exist! 
i've tried putting code inside onActivityCreated as suggested in those answers, but the problem is that the list don't get scrolled. 
moreover, whenever i click on an item, the viewPager moves to the other fragment, but not scrolling at all.

Answer (score 0):

While i wrote the question i tought of an idea which works, 
the viewPager was inside a fragment, so inside the MainActivity's onCreate
method, i checked to see if the fragment exists by using findFragmentByTag,
if it did. i replaced it with a new instance, this worked, and ended a 4 hours of looking at the computer trying to figure out what the h*** can i do..
hope this will help someone..

Answer (score 0):

When you rotate your activity is destroyed and this is the expection cause.
You can avoid it editing your manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".your activity"
   -> android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```